# Is there a way to avoid using a 'for' loop in this Pyspark code

Tags: python-3.x, for-loop, recursion, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I want to find, per genre, the average rating and total count of films from the genre in a database. However, the way the database is organized is the following: columns = [movieId, title, rating, genres], where the column genres is a list (of maximum 6 items) of the genre that apply to the movie.  How can I transform the database so that the index column is the genre with no 'for' cycles because at the moment I'm accessing each element in the list.

The following is my code:

```
import pyspark
import time
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import max,split,avg,count,col,sum,concat_ws
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("APISpark").getOrCreate()


ratings = spark.read.option("header","true").csv("input/ml25m/ratings.csv").drop("userId","timestamp")
movies = spark.read.option("header","true").csv("input/ml-25m/movies.csv")

movies = movies.withColumn('genre', split(movies['genres'], '\|') ).drop('genres')

A = movies.join(ratings,ratings["movieId"]==movies["movieId"]).drop('movieId')

F = A.groupBy(col("genre")[0]).agg(sum("rating").alias('s0'), count("title").alias('c0'))
F1 = A.groupBy(col("genre")[1]).agg(sum("rating").alias('s1'), count("title").alias('c1'))
F2 = A.groupBy(col("genre")[2]).agg(sum("rating").alias('s2'), count("title").alias('c2'))
F3 = A.groupBy(col("genre")[3]).agg(sum("rating").alias('s3'), count("title").alias('c3'))
F4 = A.groupBy(col("genre")[4]).agg(sum("rating").alias('s4'), count("title").alias('c4'))
F5 = A.groupBy(col("genre")[5]).agg(sum("rating").alias('s5'), count("title").alias('c5'))

F = F.join(F1,F['genre[0]']==F1['genre[1]'],"left").drop('genre[1]')\
     .join(F2,F2['genre[2]']==F['genre[0]'],"left").drop('genre[2]')\
     .join(F3,F3['genre[3]']==F['genre[0]'],"left").drop('genre[3]')\
     .join(F4,F4['genre[4]']==F['genre[0]'],"left").drop('genre[4]')\
     .join(F5,F5['genre[5]']==F['genre[0]'],"left").drop('genre[5]').fillna(0)

F = F.select(F[0].alias('Genres'),((F[1]+F[3]+F[5]+F[7]+F[9]+F[11])/(F[2]+F[4]+F[6]+F[8]+F[10]+F[12])).alias('Average_Rating'),(F[2]+F[4]+F[6]+F[8]+F[10]+F[12]).alias('Count'))
F.select(concat_ws(",",col("Genres"),col("Average_Rating"),col("Count")).alias("genre_averagerating_Promedio_reviews")).write.text("3_out")
```

Comment: Please add sample input and expected output.  In a meantime, take a look at `explode` function, this will flatten the array.  You can then `groupby`  https://sparkbyexamples.com/pyspark/pyspark-explode-array-and-map-columns-to-rows/

Answer (score 0):

There is a better way..far better way

#### Setup

```
A.show()

+-------+------+------+------------+
|movieId| title|rating|      genres|
+-------+------+------+------------+
|      1|movie1|     6|   [a, b, c]|
|      2|movie2|     2|      [b, c]|
|      3|movie3|     8|         [c]|
|      4|movie4|     6|[a, b, c, d]|
+-------+------+------+------------+
```

#### Solution

The key step is to `explode` the list of genre replicating each genre as a separate row then you can group the dataframe by `genre` and do aggregations.

```
result = (
    A
    .withColumn('genre', F.explode('genre'))
    .groupBy('genre').agg(
        F.count('movieId').alias('count'),
        F.mean('rating').alias('avg_rating'),
    )
)
```

#### Result

```
result.show()

+------+-----+-----------------+
|genre |count|       avg_rating|
+------+-----+-----------------+
|     c|    4|              5.5|
|     b|    3|4.666666666666667|
|     a|    2|              6.0|
|     d|    1|              6.0|
+------+-----+-----------------+
```